# Android licenses is not accepting during setting flutter environment

Tags: android, flutter

Whenever I use the command in cmd `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the android licenses for setting up flutter environment, it always give me an error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class Imran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Imran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\//

I've tried everything that I can but the issue is not resolving.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otz8B.png)

You need to download the Android tools before accepting